# JTable changing column order and then editing cell raising bug

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a strange problem with JTable.

1. What I have

A two-column JTable. And the second column uses JComboBox as a cell editor.

2. Problem

When I edit that JComboBox cell with the origin column order it works fine. **But When I change the column first, such as switching that 2 column(JComboBox column becomes fist), then I edited the JComboBox cell raising Bug.** I must click that cell twice to fire the editing event, otherwise, JComboBox isn't activated.

3. What I tried

I tried to use [TableCellListener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/), but it raises the exception, such as column index is -1;

My SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MainTable extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 156332386872772726L;

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MainTable dialog = new MainTable();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MainTable() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
        {
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            contentPanel.add(scrollPane);
            {
                table = new JTable();
                table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
                tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"first","second"},0);

                table.setModel(tableModel);
                {
                    //set comboBox to table
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
                    comboBox.addItem("Input");
                    comboBox.addItem("Output");

                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
                    table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {
                            table.requestFocusInWindow();
                            comboBox.setFocusable(true);
                            comboBox.requestFocus();
                            comboBox.grabFocus();
                            comboBox.requestFocusInWindow();//try to get focus, not worked.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

                        }
                    });
                }
//              TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, new AbstractAction(){
//                  @Override
//                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                  }
//              });
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"1","Input"});
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"2","Output"});//init. add 2 rows
                scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
            }
        }
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("Add");
                okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        int row = tableModel.getRowCount();
                        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{row,"Input"});//click button to add a row
                    }
                });
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must click that cell twice to fire the editing event, otherwise, JComboBox isn't activated.

This only happens the first time you try to edit the column after changing column order. It will also happens if you switch the column back to its original position.

It is like the table doesn't have focus so the first mouse click is giving the table focus.

So you could try to add a `TableColumnModelListener` to the `TableColumModel`. Then in the `columnMoved` event you can try using `table.requestFocusInWindow()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried your method and I found after reordering, the comboBox lost focus, after the first click, the table got focus. In columnMoved(), I add table.requestFocusInWindow() and comboBox.requestFocus(), But it didn't work.

Comment: I have solved it. Using **table.updateUI();** in columnMoved() will works!!

Comment: @lution, You should not be using updateUI(). That is invoked internally when a LAF change is made. Try wrapping the table.requestFocusInWindow() in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). That is make sure the code executes after all the column ordering logic has finished.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'll have a try.